# Displaying (Correctly?) Projected PNG onto Leaflet Map

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, proj

I am trying to overlay a PNG onto a Leaflet map.

**My GDAL commands:**

```
UL="-125.002000 52.013300"
LL="-125.002000 22.013300"
UR="-66.492200 52.013300"
LR="-66.492200 22.013300"

gdal_translate -of "GTIFF" -a_srs EPSG:4326 -gcp 0 0 ${UL} -gcp 0 1101 ${LL} -gcp 2002 0 ${UR} -gcp 2002 1101 ${LR} somefile-100.png somefile-100_ref.tif
gdalwarp -overwrite -setci -t_srs EPSG:3857 somefile-100_ref.tif somefile-100_warped.tif
gdal_translate -of PNG somefile-100_warped.tif somefile-100-final.png
```

**Source File:** https://www.dropbox.com/s/1vjxpofz0hgz3xd/somefile-100.png?dl=0

**Resulting Output:**
[image]

Something is not correct because the resulting layer should cover beyond the Continental US borders and coasts.

**Expected Output:**
[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and add relevant Leaflet code.

Comment: And something more: the two pictures above are not the same, so it's impossible to say if the first one is really wrongly placed.

Comment: Hi @TomazicM, the Leaflet code has been working great and I know that my issue lies with the source data. As for the images not matching up, that is ok because they both have the same extent in terms of the data.

Comment: Then why do you have tag Leaflet if it's irrelevant to your problem?

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. I have removed the `leaflet` tag from the question.

Comment: How do you know/calculate the bounds of the source png file